# how can i use rspec correctly?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

My code creates a github gist using the github API. After creating the gist, the API returns a status code to me. If the code is "201" the gist was created. But if it is "400" there was an error. In my code the variable that saves that state is ***response_status***

This is my code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

class Gist
   attr_reader :response_status
   attr_reader :try_again

   def initialize(filename,description,state,content)
       @filename = filename
       @description = description
       @state = state
       @content = content
   end

   def post(uri, request)
       request.basic_auth("my_username", "my_token")

       request.body = JSON.dump({
           "description" => @description,
           "public" => @state,
           "files" => {
               @filename => {
                   "content" => @content
               }
           }
       })

       req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https" }

       begin
           response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
               http.request(request)
       end

       json = response.body
       parsed = JSON.parse(json)
       @response_status = "#{ response.code }"

       if @response_status == "201"
           puts "Tu gist se ha creado con exito. La URL de su gist es: "+ parsed["url"]
       end

       rescue SocketError => se
           puts "Ha ocurrido un error de conexión. Quiere intentar nuevamente?"
           @try_again = gets.chomp.capitalize
       end
   end
end

loop do
   filename= gets.chomp

   if File.exist?("#{filename}") 
       description = gets.chomp
       state = gets.chomp.capitalize

       if state == "Si" 
           state = true;
       elsif state == "No"
           state = false;
       end

       open(filename, "r") { |file| @contenido = file.read() } 
       content = @contenido
       uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/gists")
       request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
       gist = Gist.new(filename,description,state,content)
       gist.post(uri, request)

       break if gist.response_status == "201"
       break if gist.try_again == "No"
   else
       puts "The file does not exist"
       continue = gets.chomp.capitalize
       break if continue == "No"
   end
end
```

I want to test test cases using rspec, but I did not understand.

It occurred to me as a test case that a Gist be created. For example, I thought about checking if the variable that returns the state of the Gist is equal to "201", but that didn't work for me.

This is my rspec file:

```
require './git_clases.rb'

RSpec.describe Gist do
    describe "#Gist" do
        it "#Gist created" do
            expect(response_status)==("201")
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response_status` is a method on your `Gist` object. You need to create a `Gist` object, call `post` on it, and check `response_status` on your object.

```
RSpec.describe Gist do
  # Generally organize by method
  describe "#post" do
    # Example descriptions read grammatically correct
    # "Gist #post creates a gist"
    it "creates a gist" do
      filename = "test.txt"
      description = "testing gist"
      state = "dunno what goes here"
      content = "some test content"

      gist = described_class.new(filename, description, state, content)

      uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/gists")
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
      gist.post(uri, request)

      expect(gist.response_status).to eq 201
    end
  end
end
```

[`described_class`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/metadata/described-class) is `Gist` from `RSpec.describe Gist`. It's preferable to hard coding the class name into the example in case that example becomes shared or the class name changes.

`expect(gist.response_status).to eq 201` is really `expect(gist.response_status).to( eq(201) )`. This compares `gist.response_status` using the matcher `eq(201)` which just checks that it equals 201. This might seem a bit much for a simple equality check, but it allows `rspec` to provide [a wide variety of complex matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers) as well as custom ones.

---

Your `post` method is a bit odd in that the user is expected to initialize and pass in the URL and Request object. That should probably be done by Gist.

There is no need to turn the response_status into a string. It's preferable to leave it as an Integer. If you do need it as a string, use [`response.code.to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s).